# Три зависимых списка

Tags: javascript, html, списки, css-selectors

Есть рабочий код:

```js
var users = Array('-', 'Olya', 'Vasya');
var admins = Array('-', 'Babuin', 'Org');

function showNames(v) {
  var mas = eval(v);
  var el = document.getElementById('names');

  while (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
    el.removeChild(el.childNodes[el.childNodes.length - 1]);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = mas[i];
    el.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="level" onchange="showNames(this.value)">
  <option value="admins">ADMIN</option>
  <option value="users">USER</option>
</select>
<select id="names">
</select>
```

Подскажите как корректнее его дописать с добавлением третьего списка.

То есть, чтобы значения второго брались из первого и, аналогично, третий список зависел от второго. Думаю, что функцию нужно просто продублировать, но для другого массива.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал обобщить функцию `showNames`, и передавать ей 2 параметра, первый - значение, а второй - `id` изменяемого селекта.

```js
var optionsData = {
  users: ['-', 'Оля Белова', 'Вася Белов'],
  admins: ['-', 'Babuin', 'Org'],
  'Оля Белова': ['-', '--', '---'],
  'Вася Белов': ['+', '++', '+++'],
  Babuin: ['-', '--', '---'],
  Org: ['+', '++', '+++']
};

function showNames(v, id) {
  var mas = optionsData[v] || [];
  var el = document.getElementById(id);

  el.innerHTML = '';
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

  for(var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = mas[i];
    opt.value = mas[i];
    el.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="level" onchange="showNames(this.value, 'names')">
    <option value="admins">ADMIN</option> 
    <option value="users">USER</option>
</select>

<select id="names" onchange="showNames(this.value, 'other')"></select>
<select id="other"></select>
```

Comment: то что нужно спасибо!

Comment: а может ли название объекта состоять из двух слов?
например, не 'Olya', а 'Оля Белова'. Тогда код будет такой var optionsData = { users: ['-', 'Оля Белова', 'Vasya'], admins: ['-', 'Babuin', 'Org'], Оля Белова: ['-', '--', '---'], Vasya: ['+', '++', '+++'], Babuin: ['-', '--', '---'], Org: ['+', '++', '+++'] }; При дебаге списки пусты из-за того что объект некорретно назван. Только через нишний слэш можно?

Comment: @DilmarTaktashev я исправил свой ответ, в качестве ключей у объекта можно использовать строки

Comment: Вы сделали мой день!

Comment: Реально ли присваивать id элементам третьего списка? Дело в том, что далее по коду заполняются поля в зависимости от выбранного значения в третьем списке. А значения элементов третьего списка могут одинаково называться. Или как корректнее вписать id объекта? <form action="[% Env("CGIHandle") %]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="+"> <input type="hidden" ... /> </form>

Comment: @DilmarTaktashev именно `id` нужно менять? можете менять `class` или `name`

Comment: важно понимать как вызывать конкретный объект. 
Например в строчке <form action="[% Env("CGIHandle") %]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="-"> хочу вызвать объект '-' объекта 'Оля Белова', но ведь есть объект с таким же названием у объекта 'Babuin'. Как правильно вызывать объект во вложенном массиве?

Comment: можно написать в цикле `opt.id = v + mas[i];` должны получиться уникальный `id` для `option`